# How to trigger pipeline deploy to stage using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using several Azure DevOps build and release pipelines to build and deploy a group of microservices.  I need a way to trigger deployment on multiple stages/environments on different release pipelines and I don't see anything in the REST API to support this.

I have tried using the REST API "Update Release Environment" to update the deployment status to "in progress".  This came from the answer to:  [How to redeploy TFS release using api in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665595/how-to-redeploy-tfs-release-using-api-in-powershell/46682777#46682777)

```
$deploymentbody = @" 
{"status": "inprogress"} 
"@
$request = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/Release/releases/${releaseId}/environments/${environmentId}/?api-version=5.0-preview.6"
$response = C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -u "${USERNAME}:${PAT}" "$request" -d $deploymentbody
```

The response to my attempt is "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'".

Comment: Maybe you should check the Microsoft Flow. There you can create an HTTP trigger so you can call it with powershell and then take a few actions using their integration with Azure DevOps like "Queue a new build". Hope that helps! PS: Some features of Microsoft Flow are not free.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not considered Microsoft Flow at all.  I find it interesting that there is a REST API for queueing a new build, but nothing obvious for deploying a release.