# How to schedule deployments on a stage without creating a new release every day?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops

I have a deployment pipeline in azure-devops for a repository, and it's working ok with the release schedules. But the problem is, it creates a new release for each scheduled time, even if the artifact is not changing the next day. i.e, if the repository is not being updated for a month, I have around 30 new releases for the same artifact.

The reason we need to have this kind of scheduled deployment is, we bring down all the deployed projects from our target resource group every night, and someone / something needs to deploy the latest release again to the target stages every morning.

I enabled the stage schedule under the pre-deployment conditions and set a time for it (08:00 am), it schedules for 08:00 am for the next day (and deploys). But it looks like it's not triggering another  deployment for the following day. (if there is no newer release).

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Hi @rockin'n It is by design that a new release will be created. please check out below workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Release triggered by Scheduled release triggers will create a new release. This is by design and cannot be changed. Check document [Releases in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/releases?view=azure-devops) for more information.

If you want to redeploy to a stage on a schedule without creating a new release. As a workaround you can write a script to call [release environment update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). And set a task schedule on your machine to run this script.

1, Below is an example to redeploy a stage of a release in powershell script.

You can refer to the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access) to get a Person access Token(PAT).

you can use [Release get api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the Environment Id.

```
$url ="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6"

$pat ="{PAT}"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$body='{"status": "inProgress"}'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method patch -Body $body
```

There is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665595/how-to-redeploy-tfs-release-using-api-in-powershell) to redeploy a stage via rest api in this thread. Please check it out.

2, After you have completed above script, you need to set a task schedule to run above script. Please check the detailed steps here to [Configure to run a PowerShell Script into Task Scheduler](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38580.configure-to-run-a-powershell-script-into-task-scheduler.aspx) on Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

There is option for release pipeline to set scheduled release only when source has changed.

It may require reorganization of your CI/CD flow or creating new release definition.

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, though. If I do as you say, then it will trigger a new deployment only if the source has changed. There are days that the repo doesn't get updated, but still needs to be deployed to our test stage. (This test stage gets deleted every night for cost saving)