# Azure DevOps Pipeline re-deploy if failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

i have APP which host on cluster env (1..6 nodes) behind Load Balancer, deploy process run in   consistently node-1, node-2..

Let's admit after deploy new App on node-2 Release Pipeline stopped by failed task, then we have strange situation node-1 have new version App and node-3...node-x have old version

so i thought about modify Release pipeline for blue/green analog like
for new version deploy App to temporary settings (locations, name etc) and after full deploy complete swap new to old

May be you are know more solution for this task , i think that it is typical and important issue

Comment: Are you trying to deploy Azure App Services? Question is a bit unclear to me. If possible can you provide screenshot of error so that I can help you more efficiently, Thanks :)

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you use multi-stages to deploy your app to different nodes, it is possible that some nodes fail while some succeed. So here come to your question, either you could choose the last successful release and then re-deploy that release, see this thread: [How to redeploy TFS release using api in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665595/how-to-redeploy-tfs-release-using-api-in-powershell) for details. Or debug the failed nodes and then re-deploy them.